# Can I make shallow clone the default for my repo?

Tags: git

I have a repository with many large commits. Most people who clone my repository are probably only interested in the latest version. However, the default git clone command downloads all previous versions. Is there a setting that I can change in my repository, so that `git clone --depth 1` becomes the default for anyone cloning the repo?

Comment: No. Shallow-ness, or lack thereof, is driven from the client side only and there's no advisory "here's how deep you should clone" option from server to client.

Comment: "Many large commits" makes me think you've got media files in there.  If so, convert your repo to use `git lfs` or `git annex` to get the effect you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The is no configuration setting that the client might set globally or locally to force a depth of 1 during a clone.

Only the [`git clone --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) command can make a shallow clone, on demand by the client.

As noted, using [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) can help (in order to not checkout large files), but that would not help if your issue is a large *number* of commit (where you want to limit the amount of commit fetched)